# Padding-inline-start bugged CSS animation in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-animations

## Problem

When set new CSS property called `padding-inline-start` (or other similar) it should be animatable like regular `padding`. It is defined in [CSS draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical/#propdef-padding-inline-start).

In Chrome it behaves weird and invalid. In Firefox it behaves like normal `padding-left` animation (which is what it should look like).

## Code

Example of this problem (minimum reproducible example) is here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ziom1/nxuo40za/).

## Question

Is it a bug? Can `padding-inline-start` be replaced with something similar in order to change padding in start position of the writing direction (left for LTR, right for RTL)?